# Spinner reset value when scrolling in a custom listview with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-spinner

I am a beginner in android....I need your help.

In my app I created a listview using custom adapter and custom row layout. I am successful in doing so & I have added one image, textview and a spinner drop down in all rows.  In the drop down there is number of items (from 0 to 9 for eg.)

But my problem is when I select drop down and set some value, on scrolling the list the spinner resets itself to initial value (here 0)..I am using a String of values 0 to 9 for Spinner.

What can I do to avoid this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated....Thanks in advance.

```
//This is my custom adapter code....

public class MyProductsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Products> {
Context context;
int resourceId;

Products data[] = null;

public MyProductsArrayAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
        Products data[]) {
    super(context, resourceId, data);
    this.context = context;
    this.resourceId = resourceId;

    this.data = data;
}

static class ProductsItemViewHolder {

    ImageView image;
    TextView name;
    Spinner number;
}

String[] mArray = new String[] { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",

        "8", "9" };

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    ProductsItemViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context

            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (rowView == null) {

        rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main2, parent, false);
        holder = new ProductsItemViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);

        holder.name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvListItemText);
        holder.number = (Spinner) rowView.findViewById(R.id.NumberSpinner);

        rowView.setTag(holder);

    } else {


        holder = (ProductsItemViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    Products f = data[position];
    holder.image.setImageResource(f.itemIcon);
    holder.name.setText(f.itemName);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,

            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mArray);

    holder.number.setAdapter(adapter);

    return rowView;

}
}
```

//And here is my row_layout code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_icon"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dip"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvListItemText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_icon"

    android:maxWidth="180dp"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Hello testing"
    android:textColor="@color/brown"
    android:textSize="15dp"

    android:typeface="normal" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/NumberSpinner"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `getView()` of your List's adapter, you must call `YOUR_SPINNER.setSelected(position you set earlier);`

This is happening because, once the list is created you are always getting the `convertView` in `getView` and as its default stae of spinner in it is 0 position it gets there.

Also, you are doing setAdapter to spinner always in getView method, so this will always initialize it when ever `getView()` will be called ie. on scrolling the list.

What I am saying is set `setOnItemSelectedListener()` on your `spinner` and in `onItemSelected()` method of this listener set the value as the tag of your spinner object.
`holder.number.setTag(POSITION)`

After the statement `holder.number.setAdapter()` do `holder.number.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(number.getTag));`

This way you are saving the value you selected, and you are setting the same index to it when ever the `getView()` is called.

Editted:

yes, set the value you got as parameter in method `onItemSelected(View v, int arg2)`.
This arg2 is the position system is telling you that this position is selected by you for this spinner (simple callback provided by the system).
Now, in the same method's implementation, you must set this value as the tag of this view object, which is the first argument of this callback.

Also, if you are not getting this tag value in `getView()` you must initialize your spinner every time instead of getting it from convertView, as it might contain the reused view of the row which is not in view.

Also, if you continue to get problem in implementing what I have said, you van follow another approach that make a static `HashTable<integer, integer>` where key would be the index of row and value will be the index of spinner item selected.

So, in `getView` you can set `holder.number.setSelection(hashtable.get(position));`

Comment: I tried your solution. But i am getting values 0 in first row's spinner,1 in second and etc...till last row (i guess it is the index)...but then also when i change value and scroll it again resetting it. I think i i didn't get your method properly...please give some example.

Comment: @akilis:   Thanks for your edit...but when i use gettag() i am getting null value. In my case in settag(position) what i have to set. The value i select from spinner or its index? i am confused. I tried both settag(selected value in spinner) and settag(postion of selected spinner)..in one case when i changed one spinner value and scrolled the list it is showing that value in other spinner...what is going wrong? i am unable to find out...help me

Answer (score 0):

declare the 'LayoutInflater mInflater;' as global variable.

initialize the 'mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);' inside
constructor.