# Problems with MvxSpinner in ListView

Tags: android-listview, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-spinner

I'm having a problem where I have a listview that contains a group of spinners.  If I select an option for the first spinner and then scroll down I'll see a spinner that I haven't even touched has the same value as the first spinner I just set.  I'm assuming this is an issue with the Spinner view being recycled and improperly used below.  Has anyone else ran into this issue with spinners?  I'm thinking we need to implement a solution similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261376/duplicated-entries-in-listview) in MvxAdapter?

Comment: Well looking at the MvxAdapter in the MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.View.MvxAdapter github I see the GetBindableView attempts to be handling this for normal situations.  I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258866/spinner-reset-value-when-scrolling-in-a-custom-listview-with-arrayadapter) is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my own MyMvxAdapter and MyMvxListView to handle this.  The only thing I changed in the MyMvxListView was to have it use MyMvxAdapter as its adapter instead of the normal MvxAdapter.  I then changed the GetBindableView in MyMvxAdapter to look like this:

```
        protected virtual View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId)
        {
            if (templateId == 0)
            {
                // no template seen - so use a standard string view from Android and use ToString()
                return GetSimpleView(convertView, dataContext);
            }

            // we have a templateid so lets use bind and inflate on it :)
            var viewToUse = convertView as IMvxListItemView;
            if (viewToUse != null)
            {
                if (viewToUse.TemplateId != templateId)
                {
                    viewToUse = null;
                }
            }

            if (viewToUse == null)
            {
                viewToUse = CreateBindableView(dataContext, templateId);
            }
            else
            {

                var spinner = (MvxSpinner)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.taskFieldSpinner);
                if (spinner != null)
                {
                    spinner.SetSelection(((WrappedEmployeeTaskField)dataContext).TheField.SpinnerSelection);
                }

                BindBindableView(dataContext, viewToUse);
            }

            return viewToUse as View;
        }
```

You'll notice the only real difference is that I needed to directly access my spinner resource to properly set it if viewToUse is not null.  Then the last of the "magic sauce" was to keep track of the spinner's selected value on my data model, in this case as the property "SpinnerSelection" on my model which gets filled in every time the value gets selected.