# Android Listview: How to get real item number from item position in getView()

Tags: android, listview

I need to get index of the item from start. `int position` gives position of recycled view in listview. How do I get real item number in my ArrayList in `getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method.

Comment: Use **tag** property, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045631/wrong-row-deleted-from-custom-listview-with-spinner for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by `indexOf()` method. See below code for example

```
ArrayList<String> mylist=new ArrayList<>();
mylist.add("I");
mylist.add("love");
mylist.add("You");
int index=mylist.indexOf("love");
```

Here, in `index` you will get 1. The position of content "love" in the ArrayList. And so on for all other contents.